# Is it possible to add a control dynamically inline with innerhtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, innerhtml

Does anyone know how I can add a control dynamically inline with innerhtml from code behind then capture the value when a button is clicked? Not sure how to explain this so I created example code.

.aspx

```
<div id="myTable" runat="server"></div>
<div id="result" runtat="server"></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    GetTable();
}

protected void GetTable() 
{
    string name = "Sam";
    string age = "18";
    
    TextBox txtTags = new TextBox();
    txtTags.ID = "txtBox1";
    
    myTable.InnerHtml =
        "<div>" +
            "<div>" +
                name +
            "</div>" +
            "<div>" +
                Controls.Add(txtTags) +
            "</div>" +
            "<div>" +
                age +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>";
}

protected void btnSave_Click() 
{
    string myTextbox = txtBox1.Text;
    result.InnerHtml = "Result: " + myTextbox;
}
```

Comment: This is a massive X/Y problem. Dynamically adding controls isn't done with InnerHtml. Please describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Then how do I dynamically add some html to a page, then add a control to a specific place in the created html dynamically in such a way that allows me to capture the value  of the control server side on post back?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out.

```
TextBox txtFileTags = new TextBox();
txtTags.ID = "txtBox1";

HtmlGenericControl parent1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl child1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl child2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl child3 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl child4 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

child1.InnerHtml = "Sam"
parent1.Controls.Add(child1);

child2.Controls.Add(txtTags);
parent1.Controls.Add(child2);

child3.InnerHtml = "18";
parent1.Controls.Add(child3);

myTable.Controls.Add(parent1);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetTable();
    }
}

void GetTable()
{
    string name = "Sam";
    string age = "18";

    string input = $@"

    <div>
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div><input type='text' name='txtBox1' value='' /></div>
        <div>{age}</div>
    </div>";

    myTable.InnerHtml = input;
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myTextbox = Request.Form["txtBox1"] + "";
    result.InnerHtml = "Result: " + myTextbox;
}
```